# Objective-C: Calling class 2 instance from class1 [alloc init] way is not working

Tags: objective-c, class, init, void, alloc

I've got the following method on a GameScreen.m file, with its own declaration - (void) drawNumbers on a GameScreen.h file:

```
//GameScreen.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameScreen : UIView
{
  IBOutlet UIButton *cell00;
}
- (void) drawNumbers;
- (IBAction) onCellClick:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *cell00;

@end



//GameScreen.m

#import "GameScreen.h"
- (void) drawNumbers
{
   //testing if this works, so far it doesn't
   [cell00 setTitle:@"Whatever" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [cell00 setTitle:@"Whatever" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

I'm trying to call this method from my GameScreenViewController.m file, this way:

```
//GameScreenViewController.m

#import "GameScreenViewController.h"
#import "GameScreen.h"
... 
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   GameScreen *aGameScreen = [[GameScreen alloc] init];
   [aGameScreen drawNumbers];
   [aGameScreen release];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This is supposed to change the title of a button in a GameScreen.xib file where GameScreenViewController.m is the viewController and GameScreen class is the event handler where I get all the button clicks, timers running, etc. I am trying to call [drawNumbers] from [viewDidLoad] since I want the title to be changed when the screen is brought up front (screen management is done through the AppDelegate files).

The thing is, if I call drawNumbers instance from inside the same class through

```
//GameScreen.m

#import GameScreen.h
-(void) onButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    //some other code

    [self drawNumbers];
}
```

it works (as to say, nothing wrong with the code implementation or the graphic interface).

I've browsed through Apple Guide and tons of pages on the Internet, but I can't seem to find any light to this. Any further help (including answers as to where exactly find the answer in the ADG) would be really appreciated.

(Edited: here goes the AppDelegate code to flip to the specific view, just in case):

```
//myAppAppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class myAppViewController, GameScreenViewController;
@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    myAppViewController *viewController;
    GameScreenViewController *gameScreenViewController;
}

- (void) flipToGameScreen;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GameScreenViewController *gameScreenViewController;
@end

//myAppAppDelegate.m
-(void) flipToGameScreen
{
    GameScreenViewController *aGameScreenView = [[GameScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"GameScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self setGameScreenViewController:aGameScreenView];
    [aGameScreenView release];
    [gameScreenViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[gameScreenViewController view]];
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of GameScreen.h?

Comment: How is your `cell00` instance variable in `GameScreen` set? That isn't shown here, and it could be `nil` at the time you call the `-drawNumbers` method.

Comment: edited as requested. you can see there cell instance variable as well.

Comment: In your GamesViewController.m viewDidLoad method change this line [GameScreen release];  to [aGameScreen release];

Comment: Typo here, my bad. explanation edited. Would you need the AppDelegate file as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `cell00` is to be set by a NIB it will be nil if you simply do `[[GameScreen alloc] init]`. It will only be set if the corresponding NIB is loaded (and a connection is actually set up).

If the cell can be accessed in your `viewDidLoad`, create a property on `GameScreen` and pass it through the property (or a dedicated `initWithCell:` or something).

If you have something like an `IBOutlet GameScreen *aGameScreen;` on your `GameScreenViewController` (and also established a connection to `cell00` in the same NIB) you should access that instead.

Comment: I don't get it then; if all views are triggered from an AppDelegate through a specific method -(void) fliptoScreenX and the view is added, don't both the viewController and the class get loaded when the xib is displayed, since viewController is related to File's Owner and GameScreen to the view?

Comment: "small" workaround: it'd work if I had the IBOutlets on the ViewController class and the IBActions on the GameScreen class? I've got over 20 buttons, that means to double all variables, not a good thing...

is it OK (from a 'keep it clean and simple' point of view)?

Comment: A NIB/XIB is *deserialized*. This means that all the objects in it get decoded (via `NSCoder`) and the associations/connections are made *during loading*. Once you reach `viewDidLoad` that's done. All object that get created by you then do not have any relations with the NIB/XIB. If you do `[[GameScreen alloc] init]`, none of your `IBOutlet`s of that instance get connected. Be sure to read the whole [Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) section of the *Resource Programming Guide*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I really appreciate it. Will do so, in the meanwhile I've decide to twist my code a bit: AppDelegate will work as view manager, ViewControllers will act as output, and classes will act as input. That way I can stick to the MVC model and still have clean code... thanks again, indeed.